# Ubuntu Install blocked by graphics card

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, hp, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an HP Envy desktop PC. The PC has an Rtx 3060ti graphics card, which blocks the installation process. There are some solutions posted in articles that I have tried, such as adding nomodeset to the command, disabling secure boot, and changing the SATA connection from RAID to AHCI. All these solutions failed to work.

Note: The PC already has Windows 11, and I plan to dual boot Windows and Linux.

System specs:

- CPU: i7-11700f
- GPU: RTX 3060ti
- 1TB hard drive
- 512GB SSD
- model: HP ENVY Desktop PC TPE01-2000

[image]